# How to fix cyrillic symbols path error in xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I try to run fresh solution in xamarin but get an error "Unable to open file or read: Invalid argument".
I think that the **problem is cyrillic user name**. Is there a way to fix it without renaming user?

Error: 
**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to open file for read: Invalid argument  HelloCrossPlatformWorld.Droid   C:\Users\???????\AppData\Local\Temp\3lmzv4g2.pvd\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml**

Output: 
Starting runtime checks
Starting emulator Nexus_5X_API_28 ...
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloCrossPlatformWorld.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\android\SDK\emulator\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Nexus_5X_API_28 -prop monodroid.avdname=Nexus_5X_API_28
ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 1 M to 2048 M

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-0c7d255f-7f0b-4ce7-a760-4dae02030c12-5340-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-0e3a40e7-e147-4ccc-b03c-cd98b7177a26-9860-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-10035f6b-dfc5-4e8a-918c-3e946b07dafb-1320-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-209243bb-de89-451c-9bc0-4a73ec160244-15848-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-30f48f7d-5e23-446e-9b1c-01a8ebf8d009-1332-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-3ab578be-f274-4fdc-bd59-a193eb4ee885-4188-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-43cbcfd5-87fa-4745-b344-87864ac452f9-100-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-49f1fada-3e7c-41a1-b230-c40b2418f32b-8668-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-4b1a0ab3-e7ed-4ae0-8414-28d2eed9881a-6940-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-4c0abb15-350e-4cad-b779-3a4f8e073c6e-10816-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-4c6a3df0-29f7-428b-ae99-c3e4b2c1160b-14012-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-4d871e93-b5cf-4b13-9a3b-622d8899174d-3956-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-56279d77-95dc-4c60-afb7-7be2701ed0e2-4052-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-56ee4e18-3d5b-4e0f-b6fe-bd690ee15f4b-14884-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-57376a39-7192-48e2-9641-08d50f302a2f-14216-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-5d8915da-10e6-435d-9164-6dbcb3c38497-15352-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-5fdb91d2-0a4a-40e5-9223-8dbb0f78e1c3-18260-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-6cd3a315-2d12-4e89-976a-dae74ef90670-4456-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-732f3b1d-b9e7-4481-83a4-230e904f9b42-15956-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-732f3b1d-b9e7-4481-83a4-230e904f9b42-15956-1001.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-80958925-8ba3-4949-a6b4-ff22214ae0f4-12244-0.open'
1>C:\Users\???????\AppData\Local\Temp\3lmzv4g2.pvd\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml : error APT0000: Unable to open file for read: Invalid argument
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
emulator: WARNING: Not saving state: emulator hasn't finished booting.
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an active log file 'C:\Users\Ð­Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹.android\metrics\spool\emulator-metrics-961b5120-9240-4028-b7b9-e4f383a1902f-13524-0.open'
emulator: WARNING: (metrics) failed to rename an abandoned log file 'emulator-metrics-961b5120-9240-4028-b7b9-e4f383a1902f-13524-0.open'
Emulator Nexus_5X_API_28 was stopped.
Runtime checks completed

Comment: you could just save the project on another drive

Comment: @Scarnet I tried but it uses roaming directory anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just reset the computer and changed the letters of the user name to Latin. Now it's works fine.